# Getting two or more images ids from the same column

Tags: php, mysql

I got a MySQL table with one or more comma separated numbers in it. Those numbers refer to ID's in another MySQL table, witch also includes the name of a image.

I want to select a row where the field "images" contains "1,43" and display the two images with ID 1 and 43 from the 2nd table.

Do I have to have the two numbers in differents fields? I'd prefer keep them in the same one.

Comment: Don't do this. Please! Normalise your database ([Simple](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/283878) | [Technical](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html)) and make your life easier, as well as the lives of every developer who has to maintain that code after you're gone. Use a one-to-many table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET`. Assuming you have the table like this below,

Table1

```
+++++++++++
Images
+++++++++++
1,43
```

Table2

```
+++++++++++++++++
ImageID  Image
+++++++++++++++++
1        ....
43       ....
```

Sample Query:

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.ImageID, a.Images) > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e09c2/1)

If you have time to modify the structure of the table. Please do. The query above will perform slow if you are doing it on large databases.

Comment: And if you don't have time to modify the database structure, still do.